# Installed 12.04 via WUBI, now monitor problems

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, wubi

Had to revive an old desk top because my oldest dumped Sprite on our laptop.  Ouch!

Anyway, I installed 12.04 on this Vista machine (e-machines, AMD Athlon).  The install went fine, when I rebooted and selected Ubuntu it appears the graphics card drops out as the monitor shows a message "out of range" if I'm not mistaken.  Maybe the Ubuntu install doesn't recognize the NVidia graphics card?  How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: are you sure you are having the latest drivers for your vedio card? Just run `sudo lspci -v | less` and check if your vedio card is recognised

Comment: I can't even get that far.  I just get the monitor's status and Ubuntu never boots.  In fact after a minute or so the monitor goes into power save mode while the pc stays on.